# Draw a fixed sized rectangle in image on click and change its location by moving the mouse

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, mouseevent

I need to draw a rectangle of fixed size in image when left mouse button is clicked, and change its location in the image by moving the mouse. 
I came up with this code, which basically draws rectangle in image, where mouse pointer is intersection point of diagonals of rectangle.

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

#flags
move_rectangle = False

#color for rectangle
BLUE = [255,0,0]

def mouse(event,x,y,flags,params):
    global move_rectangle, BLUE

    #draw rectangle where x,y is rectangle center
    if event == cv.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        move_rectangle = True

    elif event == cv.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if move_rectangle:
            cv.rectangle(bg,(x-int(0.5*cols),y-int(0.5*rows)),
            (x+int(0.5*cols),y+int(0.5*rows)),BLUE, -1)

    elif event == cv.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        move_rectangle = False
        cv.rectangle(bg,(x-int(0.5*cols),y-int(0.5*rows)),
        (x+int(0.5*cols),y+int(0.5*rows)),BLUE, -1)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    #loading images
    fg = cv.imread('sample.jpg')
    bg = cv.imread('beach.jpg')
    #grabing height and width of foreground image
    rows, cols = fg.shape[:2]

    cv.namedWindow('draw')
    cv.setMouseCallback('draw', mouse)

    while True:

        cv.imshow('draw', bg)
        k = cv.waitKey(1)

        #waiting for esc to exit
        if k == 27 & 0xFF:
            break

    cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

However, i can't figure out how to make it draw rectangle only in the position of mouse pointer. I need to get rid of that "shadow" behind front rectangle.

Shadow

[image: image description]

How this can be done?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "draw rectangle only in the position of mouse pointer".  Also, I don't see a "shadow" - what do you mean by shadow ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe what you need to do is simply reinitialize your image when you receive move event

```
import cv2 as cv

move_rectangle = False
BLUE = [255,0,0]

fg = cv.imread('sample.jpg')
bg = cv.imread('beach.jpg')
bgCopy = bg.copy()

def mouse(event,x,y,flags,params):
    global move_rectangle, BLUE, fg, bg, bgCopy
    #draw rectangle where x,y is rectangle center
    if event == cv.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        move_rectangle = True

    elif event == cv.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        bg = bgCopy.copy() #!! your image is reinitialized with initial one
        if move_rectangle:
            cv.rectangle(bg,(x-int(0.5*cols),y-int(0.5*rows)),
            (x+int(0.5*cols),y+int(0.5*rows)),BLUE, -1)

    elif event == cv.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        move_rectangle = False
        cv.rectangle(bg,(x-int(0.5*cols),y-int(0.5*rows)),
        (x+int(0.5*cols),y+int(0.5*rows)),BLUE, -1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rows, cols = fg.shape[:2]

    cv.namedWindow('draw')
    cv.setMouseCallback('draw', mouse)

    while True:

        cv.imshow('draw', bg)
        k = cv.waitKey(1)

        #waiting for esc to exit
        if k == 27 & 0xFF:
            break

    cv.destroyAllWindows()
```